# How can I export the "available software to download" to a file?

Tags: update-manager

Sometimes Ubuntu will show a popup like this:

[image]

(It looks weird because I'm using [Regolith](https://regolith-linux.org/))

How can I export the list of packages/changes Ubuntu wants to install to a file? This is for debugging purposes - I think something in this update is breaking my system, and I want to be able to be able to figure out exactly where the break is coming from.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open a terminal and type the following:

```
sudo apt update
apt list --upgradable > ~/downloadable.txt
```

The list of software available to download will be saved to a file named `downloadable.txt` in your home folder.

You can ignore the following warning in this case...

```
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use `apt-get`

```
sudo apt-get update

yes no | sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  > ~/upgradeable.txt
```

You can find the list in your home directory and at the bottom of the file, you'll see something like this:

```
123 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 180 MB/197 MB of archives.
After this operation, 89,1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

Which can indicate how long the installation of upgrades will take.